# Image not showing when I delete the border HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

The image is not showing when I delete "border: 1px solid black;" can anyone figure this out? I tried but I can't! So I really hope someone can figure this out!

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">

          <div class="main-width">

           <h1>logo</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Your journey starts here.</a></li>
            </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="banner">
            <div id="home-image">
            <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="home image"> 
        </div>     
        </section>
    </main>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#home-image {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:70vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#home-image img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top:-35vh
}
```

Here is a fiddel with the full source code: [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/remcomayr/boysbx6y/5)

Comment: What is your Problem? Do you get an Error Message?

Comment: This can't be happen generally, can you create a jsfiddle version?

Comment: What u mean? I'm new and I don't know much about this website yet, excuse me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your example works for me, providing some random google image. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr8t7qqt/).

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">

          <div class="main-width">

           <h1>logo</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Your journey starts here.</a></li>
            </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="banner">
            <div id="home-image">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" alt="home image"> 
        </div>     
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

**Update:** Just to make it clear, the fiddle contains this CSS:

```
#home-image {
    height:70vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#home-image img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top:-35vh
}
```

Make sure that the path of your image is valid.

**2nd. Update:** The problem is that you are using `overflow: hidden` without providing an explicit width for `#home-image`.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what i meant. when I delete the border in the #home-image the whole image disappears. That's what the problem is. If I add inline-block to the css #home-image it shows but I don't think it is the right way to show the picture again.

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed description of your problem? I deleted the `border: 1px solid black;` in the fiddle and had to provide another image to display because your image is not available to me. This is the setup you described in your original question.

Comment: Okay so, the image shows up with the code I sent in my question, right? Now if I delete the border: 1px solid black in the CSS the picture don't show up anymore. So the problem is that the image doesn't show when I delete that sentence on my CSS

Comment: Can you please watch at the fiddle i provided in my answer and compare it to your code? It should be your setup, just with another image.

Comment: I tried it, but without the border: 1px solid black; it won't show up, copy my code, and delete the border. The picture will not show up then, only with the border around it

Comment: Thats not what i expected you to do, in my answer is a link to a runnable demonstration on jsfiddle, which shows the image (and without the border css property). Can you please compare the code in the fiddle with your local code and spot the differences between them?

Comment: Yes, that works for me aswell. Maybe it's because my other CSS code?

Comment: The runnable example on jsfiddle contains your CSS code without the border property.

Comment: Yes, I see. I think it does not show up because of my other CSS codes.. I added the codes and it's invisible again.

Comment: Can you check for any problems in my other CSS code? https://jsfiddle.net/boysbx6y/

Comment: You are trying to serve an image which is on your local machine propably (`images/image4.jpg`) in this fiddle, so it is not visible.

Comment: The problem with your code is you are using `overflow: hidden` without providing an explicit width for `#home-image`. Please update your original question to provide this fiddle so others know whats going on.

Comment: I have updated my answer to state the correct solution. Is the answer helpful now?

Comment: Good to hear :) Can you please update your question to include the link to your fiddle? The question could not be solved until you shared your full code so it may be useful to others. If my answer was correct and youare happy with it, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Where do I need to share the fiddle?

Comment: It would be nice if you edit your original question to include the link to the fiddle you posted above, so other viewers have all the source code without to read this comments under my answer.